# stream audio with screen off

Tags: android, media-player

I'm trying to stream an audio file while the screen is oFF. I'm using the MediaPlayer class.
I've managed to play the audio (mp3) while the screen is ON. Also to play a video while the screen is OFF.These two worked well.
However, when I play the audio while the screen is OFF I got the following messages in logcat:

```
06-16 13:52:22.977: WARN/TimedEventQueue(59): Event 3 was not found in the queue, already cancelled?
06-16 13:52:23.207: WARN/MediaPlayer(11489): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
06-16 13:52:23.207: WARN/MediaPlayer(11489): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
```

I've tried to use a wakelock without succeed:

```
mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getBaseContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
```

Any other suggestion of what should I try?

really appreciate your help,

/cristobal

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple solution, but are you running the mediaplayer part of the code in a Service?
If you are not, that is the problem.

See [this](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html) for more about services. Also the [Android docs about services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

See [the official Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices) for more about running media from a service (while your application is paused, screen is off, etc.)